# Java: Can I run a given method in my program without invocating from main?

Tags: java, eclipse

Is there a way to launch methods written in Java from Eclipse without having to write all the driver code for it? I would like some effecient way of just right clicking a method, populating it with params and feeding it a debugger.

Comment: BlueJ can do something like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest I can think of is the "scrap page" in eclipse.  Don't think you can debug though.

If I were you, I'd use moreUnit plugin + JUnit (+ preferably maven). That way, you can not only write some tests quickly, but they will be organized so that you can have a nice unit test battery afterwards...

Comment: I agree with Zwei here that JUnit is a good solution.  You can select "File > New > JUnit Test Case" for a given class to have Eclipse generate all the skeletal code for a JUnit class.  Then you just need to invoke your method with the parameters you want in the test method, and you have a ready-to-go test harness.  Set a breakpoint and then right click on the JUnit test method and select "Debug As > JUnit Test"

Answer (score 0):

This is not part of any standard eclipse plugin that comes in the stock package.